# emplace and try_emplace with copy constructor

Tags: c++, dictionary, try-catch, emplace

I have an issue with emplace and try_emplace as they always use the copy constructors when moving an object in.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

class Too {
public:
     Too(int x, int y):x_(x), y_(y) {
        cout << "init " << x_  << endl;
    }
    Too(const Too& too):x_(too.x_+1), y_(too.y_+1) {
        cout << "Copy happen: x = " << x_ << endl;
     }
    ~Too() {
        cout << "delete too " << x_ << endl;
    }
private:
    int x_, y_;
};



std::map<int, Too> v;


int main()
{
    v.emplace(100, Too{ 100,23 });

    v.try_emplace(12, 12, 13);

    Too t = Too(10, 11);
    v.try_emplace(11, std::move(t));
}
```

---

output
init 100
Copy happen: x = 101
delete too 100
init 12
init 10
Copy happen: x = 11
delete too 10
delete too 101
delete too 12
delete too 11

---

As you can see, only     v.try_emplace(12, 12, 13) do not use the copy constructor.
both     v.emplace(100, Too{ 100,23 }) and v.try_emplace(11, std::move(t)) invoke the copy constructor.

So how can it be even when I use std::move(t)?

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: When there is no move ctor available for your class, copy ctor will be used.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three Follow the rule of zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've provided a copy constructor for your class, the move constructor `Too::Too(Too&&)` will **not be implicitly generated by the compiler**.

Moreover, when there is no move constructor available for a class, the copy constructor can be used.

---

For using the move constructor you have to explicitly provide an appropriate user-defined move constructor `Too::Too(Too&&)`, then you will get the desired result.

You can add the move constructor either by adding `Too(Too&&) = default;` or writing your own move constructor which will do the initialization in the constructor initializer list.